# Why is my JSON URL not outputting JSON data?

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have checked the URL and it works but when I try to output the `readableJSON`, it is empty?!

Here is my output:

```
Not empty now
2016-02-20 10:19:29.162 ThisLondon[55922:4080604] the URL: [

]
2016-02-20 10:19:29.162 ThisLondon[55922:4080604] 0
```

Here is my code:

```
selectedTube = "Circle"
let url = NSURL(string: "https://api.tfl.gov.uk/Line/\(selectedTube)/Arrivals?app_id=6573044a&app_key=7a97df35339dc68625384077a5e07304")
let jsonData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
let readableJSON = JSON(data: jsonData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil)

NSLog("the URL: \(readableJSON)")
```

Comment: Paste the literal URL in a browser and check the result.

Comment: The following LOC is the issue. You're doing the other things correctly.

let readableJSON = JSON(data: jsonData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil)

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
    let selectedTube = "circle"
        let headers = ["cache-control": "no-cache",]

let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://api.tfl.gov.uk/Line/\(selectedTube)/Arrivals?app_id=6573044a&app_key=7a97df35339dc68625384077a5e07304")!,
                                                cachePolicy: .UseProtocolCachePolicy,
                                            timeoutInterval: 10.0)
        request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
        request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers

        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let dataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
          if (error != nil) {
            print(error)
          } else {
            let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse
            print(httpResponse)
          }
        })

        dataTask.resume()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what your problem is. The following code works just fine in a playground. I would suspect the problem lies within your custom `JSON` function:

```
import Foundation

let selectedTube = "Circle"
let url = NSURL(string: "https://api.tfl.gov.uk/Line/\(selectedTube)/Arrivals?app_id=6573044a&app_key=7a97df35339dc68625384077a5e07304")
if let jsonData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!) {
    let readableJSON = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)
    NSLog("the URL: \(readableJSON)")
} else {
        print("Cannot read data.")
}
```